# How to use Powershell to batch copy files and output their success or failure to a log file

Tags: powershell, copy-item, passthru

I want to copy a series of files from different locations/destinations and output their success and/or failure to a pipe delimited file.

For example I have tried the code below but it doesn't report failures and I would also like the output to be clearer so I can consume this into excel and clearly see what copied and what failed.

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source_1\111a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc1.docx" -PassThru | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Output\copy_results.txt" -Append
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source_2\222a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc2.docx" -PassThru | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Output\copy_results.txt" -Append
```

Is there a way to do this so I have an output file that looks something the below, assuming the second file was to fail in the above example

> Path "C:\Source_1\111a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" | -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc1.docx" | File copied successfully
> -Path "C:\Source_2\222a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc2.docx" | Error Reason

For example I have tried the code below but it doesn't report failures and I would also like the output to be clearer so I can consume this into excel and clearly see what copied and what failed.

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source_1\111a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc1.docx" -PassThru | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Output\copy_results.txt" -Append
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Source_2\222a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc2.docx" -PassThru | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Output\copy_results.txt" -Append
```

Is there a way to do this so I have an output file that looks something the below, assuming the second file was to fail in the above example

> Path "C:\Source_1\111a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" | -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc1.docx" | File copied successfully
> -Path "C:\Source_2\222a46bf-cc88-48c1-b20a-cc8f897dec84.docx" -Destination "C:\Destination_1\Renamed_Word_Doc2.docx" | Error Reason

Comment: Quick thoughts: `Start-Transcript $log` or using `try{}catch{}` blocks, and/or perhaps using the `-verbose` switch.

Comment: you may try writing everything to the success stream: `Copy-Item .... -Verbose *>&1 | Out-File ....`

Comment: Thanks for the input but Start-Transcript or -Verbose do not format the output file is a user friendly pipe delimited way so I can see what copied from A to B with a "Success" or "Failure + Error Reason".  I will keep playing to see if Powershell is even the best solution for this.

Comment: Might need some fancier PowerShell looping your copies and wrapping in a `try{}catch{}` block to capture success or failure (e.g. `$_.Exception.Message`) and listing `$_.FullName` for an idea of something else to play with.